# How I can iterate second for loop while using array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

```
I have array which  length is 13 .
form has 13 simultaneous  fields user can enter in any field i want that if user  enter   5 or 7 or any field value then i want add validation that it's previous field  value should not be empty and it should not check validation for next field.
```

I have used this code ...

```
datesId[0] = "bankNocForTorDateId";

datesId[1] = "advertisingDateShortlistingId";
datesId[2] = "torShortlistFinalizedDateId";
datesId[3] = "bankNocForShortlistDateId";
datesId[4] = "rfpDraftToBankDateId";
datesId[5] = "bankNocForRfpDateId";
datesId[6] = "rfpIssuedDateId";
datesId[7] = "proposalReciptDateTechnicalId";
datesId[8] = "evaluationFinalTechnicalDateId";
datesId[9] = "bankNocTechnicalDateId";
datesId[10] = "proposalReciptDateFinancialId";
datesId[11] = "evaluationFinalCombinedDateId";
datesId[12] = "nocBankDraftDate";



for(var i = 0; i<datesId.length ; i++ ){
  if(!(document.getElementById (datesId[i]).value == "")){
    for(var j =datesId[i].length-1 ;j>0 ; j-- ){
      if(document.getElementById(datesId[j]).value == ""){
        var message = "Please Enter "+datesLabel[j];
        alert(message);
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Actually i am new in Javascript...not having much idea about it.I have made this logic on the basis of java. please clearify what's basic difference.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'm curious -- you talk about Javascript, and your code looks like Javascript, but not only do you tag Java, but you tag Spring and Struts, which AFAIK are Java-only frameworks. Why?

Comment: Actually i am new so i don't have much idea about this.

Comment: ok but can you tell me what should i do to resolve this problem

Comment: @user3595144 I'd advise you read the little things that appear when you hover over the tags, and only add tags that are relevant to your problem. Otherwise you get people like me who don't know Javascript reading your question.

Comment: thanks bt can you tell how i can iterate this one .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done!

```
var datesId = []
datesId[0] = "bankNocForTorDateId";
datesId[1] = "advertisingDateShortlistingId";
datesId[2] = "torShortlistFinalizedDateId";
datesId[3] = "bankNocForShortlistDateId";
datesId[4] = "rfpDraftToBankDateId";
datesId[5] = "bankNocForRfpDateId";
datesId[6] = "rfpIssuedDateId";
datesId[7] = "proposalReciptDateTechnicalId";
datesId[8] = "evaluationFinalTechnicalDateId";
datesId[9] = "bankNocTechnicalDateId";
datesId[10] = "proposalReciptDateFinancialId";
datesId[11] = "evaluationFinalCombinedDateId";
datesId[12] = "nocBankDraftDate";

// if datesId[6] value is not blank
if (datesId[6] != ''){
  // validate previous 5 field values should not be blank, but it should not check next 6 value.
  for (var i = (6-5); i < 6; i ++){
    console.log('validating field ' + datesId[i] + " (index=" + i + ")")
    if (datesId[i] == ''){
      alert('Field ' + datesId[i] + " must not be blank!")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi you have used fixed case but user can enter any value that means user will enter value from form so  next value should not checked of entered value but it must validate previous value .

Comment: I don't understand. Maybe you can provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: i mean in my form there are 13 field  for date simultanously  . user can enter any field value. but i want that if user enter any field value then it's previous value should not be empty but next value it should not checked.